# Coldfusion 9 determine all session scope memory used

Tags: coldfusion, jvm

We are running Coldfusion 9.0.2 multi instance, JVM1.7.0_25  on a windows 2008 server. Coldfusion instance 2's memory has grown and is staying high even though there aren't a lot of requests when I look at it. According to Fusion Reactor the Old Gen is using most of the memory which leads me to ask why. It looks like there are about 270 active sessions. I would like to see how much memory is being used by each session and what session variables are in each session. Any ideas for either of these?

Thanks in advance.
Joe

Answer (score 0):

Joe, you are using the Enterprise edition of ColdFusion so you have built in Monitoring Tools. Log into the CF Admin for the instance you want to monitor and enable and launch Monitoring. There is a section in monitoring that will show you how much memory is being used by each CF Application and by each user Session. To see this data you need to enable Memory Profiling. It is advised that this feature remain disable except for the time you need to look at data then turn it off again. Memory Profiling can add a lot of extra load to the server in some cases.